# Hidden folders C#

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# - Get a list of files excluding those that are hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418270/c-get-a-list-of-files-excluding-those-that-are-hidden)

How do i make sure that i only get the folders that are NOT hidden?

this is what i do know but it returns all folders.

```
string[] folders = Directory.GetDirectories(path);
```

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418270/c-get-a-list-of-files-excluding-those-that-are-hidden

Comment: The same type of check on directory attributes should work here.

Comment: It's exactly the same principle. Just change line 2 to "GetDirectories" instead.

Comment: @Profeten I know but the same principle applies that you check the FileAttributes property for Hidden

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [DirectoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx?queryresult=true) to check if a folder is hidden:

```
string[] folders = Directory.GetDirectories(path);
foreach (string subFolder in folders) {
 string folder = Path.Combine(path, subFolder);
 DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(folder);
 if ((info.Attributes & FileAttributes.Hidden) == FileAttributes.Hidden) {
  // do something with your non-hidden folder here
 }
}
```

Another solution would be the following one-liner:

```
var folders = new DirectoryInfo(path).GetDirectories().Where(x => (x.Attributes & FileAttributes.Hidden) == 0);
```

In this case `folders` is an `IEnumberable<DirectoryInfo>`.
If you want files instead of directories, simply replace GetDirectories with GetFiles.

Answer (score 5):

You would need to loop the directories and check the ( attrib *utes* ) for that directory or file.

Example:

```
foreach (DirectoryInfo Dir in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
{
    if (!Dir.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Hidden))
    {
        //Add to List<DirectoryInfo>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like

```
var dirs = Directory.GetDirectories("C:").Select(dir => new DirectoryInfo(dir))
    .Where(dirInfo => (!dirInfo.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Hidden)));
```