# Multiple optional checks with Where query (to specify file search options)

Tags: c#, linq

I created checkboxes, where a user can set this for file searching:

1. exclude system files: on/off
2. exclude hidden files: on/off
3. exclude read_only files: on/off

now I don't know, how I can use this three different boolean statements with this code line:

```
DirectoryInfo DirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(sCopyFilesFromFilePath);                    
GetDirsToCopy = 
   DirInfo.EnumerateDirectories(".", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where( ? );
```

Comment: You enumerate over directories, not files...

Comment: May be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418270/c-sharp-get-a-list-of-files-excluding-those-that-are-hidden

Comment: Could you please clarify how reading directories is related to "file searching" and whether you what problems you have reading `DirectoryInfo` / `FileSystemInfo` documentation.

Comment: A file's FileAttributes is a bitmask, so create one based on the selection and examine File.GetAttributes() for each candidate file

Comment: StefanS, I've edited title of your post to hopefully better reflect problem you have instead of complete task. Feel free to rollback/improve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an implication. In logic `a -> b` is translated as `!a || b`, thus:

```
DirInfo.EnumerateDirectories(".", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
       .Where(x => !excludeSystem || (x.Attributes&FileAttributes.System) == 0);
       .Where(x => !excludeHidden || (x.Attributes&FileAttributes.Hidden) == 0);
       .Where(x => !excludeReadOnly || (x.Attributes&FileAttributes.ReadOnly) == 0);
```

Here we assume `excludeSystem`, `excludeHidden` and `excludeReadOnly` are `bool`s that you first fetched from the checkboxes.

You can of course write it in one `Where` as well.

**Explanation** (one `.Where`):

Given the following expression

```
x => !excludeSystem || (x.Attributes&FileAttributes.System) == 0
```

You can read this as a predicate. Say `excludeSystem` is `false`, then `!excludeSystem` is `true`, thus all directories will succeed. If not, the the second operand `(x.Attributes&FileAttributes.System) == 0` is executed.

The second operand first does and bitwise `&` on the `Attributes` of `x` and the constant `FileAttributes.System`. If the `Attributes` thus contain `FileAttributes.System`, the result will be something different than zero. In that case the second test fails. In other words, you return `false` if the files are excluded and the file is a system-file.

**Optimize**

In case you think you will iterate over thousands of directories, you can make the code a bit more efficient, by making the tests faster:

```
IEnumerable<DirectoryInfo> temp = DirInfo.EnumerateDirectories(".", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
if(excludeSystem) {
    temp = temp.Where((x.Attributes&FileAttributes.System) == 0);
}
if(excludeHidden) {
    temp = temp.Where((x.Attributes&FileAttributes.Hidden) == 0);
}
if(excludeReadOnly) {
    temp = temp.Where((x.Attributes&FileAttributes.ReadOnly) == 0);
}
GetDirsToCopy = temp;
```

This will (almost) always be efficient, but it makes the code a bit less beautiful.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know, how to exclude the folder "System Volume Information"? There is always an exception.

Comment: @StefanS: what do you mean with exception? Can you give the stacktrace?

Comment: I am sorry, I was lazy yesterday. Every Windows root partition like C: or D: has a folder named "System Volume Information" and that folder is not detected by the linq code. I think this happens, because of        "DirInfo.EnumerateDirectories". So I have to build a way around it.