# Get all files except files in hidden directories?

Tags: c#

I want to create a list of all the files in a directory, except hidden fies and files inside hidden folder in the directory. I used this method,

```
new DirectoryInfo(path).GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                     .Where(f => (f.Attributes & FileAttributes.Hidden) == 0)
```

But the above method return files inside hidden folders. Are there any other way to do this without recursively iterating through directories?

Comment: Is it possible to have a file which is NOT hidden in a directory which IS hidden ?

Comment: Don't think so, I'm afraid. Though it probably doesn't require that much code.

Comment: @DimitarTsonev: Yes it is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# - Get a list of files excluding those that are hidden](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418270/c-sharp-get-a-list-of-files-excluding-those-that-are-hidden)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way without "manually iterating" would be the following:

```
var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
var hiddenFolders = dirInfo.GetDirectories("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Where(d => (d.Attributes & FileAttributes.Hidden) != 0)
    .Select(d => d.FullName);

var files = dirInfo.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Where(f => (f.Attributes & FileAttributes.Hidden) == 0 && 
        !hiddenFolders.Any(d => f.FullName.StartsWith(d)));
```

**BUT** this will be iterating the whole directory tree twice and has the `.Any`-overhead for every file => use @Catburry's solution as it has a better performance and is easier to maintain IMO...

Answer (score 8):

Thats because the Files in the hidden-subfolders aren't hidden.
To Check this you have to walk recursively to each folder & check the Folder-Attributes too.

**Example function:**

```
   private static IList<FileInfo> getNonHidden(DirectoryInfo baseDirectory)
    {
        var fileInfos = new List<System.IO.FileInfo>();
        fileInfos.AddRange(baseDirectory.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Where(w => (w.Attributes & FileAttributes.Hidden) == 0));
        foreach (var directory in baseDirectory.GetDirectories("*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Where(w => (w.Attributes & FileAttributes.Hidden) == 0))
            fileInfos.AddRange(getNonHiddenFiles(directory));

        return fileInfos;
    }
```

**How to use:**

```
  var path = @"c:\temp\123";
  var result = getNonHidden(new DirectoryInfo(path));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
foreach (DirectoryInfo Dir in Directory.GetDirectories(directorypath))
{
    if (!Dir.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Hidden))
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you try below code:

```
var x = new DirectoryInfo(@"D://Priyank Sheth/Projects/").GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                     .Where(f => (f.Directory.Attributes & FileAttributes.Hidden) == 0 && (f.Attributes & FileAttributes.Hidden) == 0);
```

I have not tried it but let me know if it does not work.