# How to use Directory.EnumerateFiles excluding hidden and system files

Tags: c#, ienumerable, fileinfo

I'm enumerating all files in a directory so that I can process them later. I want to exclude hidden and system files.

This is what I have so far:

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, string>> files;

files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourcePath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
       .Where(f => (new FileInfo(f).Attributes & FileAttributes.Hidden & FileAttributes.System) == 0)
       .GroupBy(Path.GetDirectoryName);
```

However if I look at the results I am still getting hidden and system files included:

```
foreach (var folder in files)
{
    foreach (var file in folder)
    {
        // value for file here still shows hidden/system file paths
    }
}
```

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418270/c-sharp-get-a-list-of-files-excluding-those-that-are-hidden) which has a similar example from Jerome but I couldn't even get that to compile.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `FileAttributes.Hidden & FileAttributes.System` always equals 0.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realise that. I tried `(new FileInfo(f).Attributes & FileAttributes.Hidden) != FileAttributes.Hidden)` which works but I struggled to figure out how to include system files in this as well.

Comment: Adding to that, if you are going to create a new FileInfo, start from DirectoryInfo so you get FileInfo objects from the start. As for the filter, try `fi.Attributes & (FileAttributes.Hidden | FileAttributes.System)) == 0`. First create the mask you want `FileAttributes.Hidden | FileAttributes.System` and *then* do a bitwise AND. The folder path is also available through `FileInfo.DirectoryName`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
.Where(f => (new FileInfo(f).Attributes & FileAttributes.Hidden & FileAttributes.System) == 0)
```

Since [`FileAttributes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileattributes.aspx) values are flags, they are disjunctive on the bit level, so you can combine them properly. As such, `FileAttributes.Hidden & FileAttributes.System` will always be `0`. So you’re essentially checking for the following:

```
(new FileInfo(f).Attributes & 0) == 0
```

And that will always be true since you are removing any value with the `& 0` part.

What you want to check is whether the file has neither of those flags, or in other words, if there are no common flags with the combination of both:

```
.Where(f => (new FileInfo(f).Attributes & (FileAttributes.Hidden | FileAttributes.System)) == 0)
```

You can also use [`Enum.HasFlag`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag.aspx) to make this a bit better understandable:

```
.Where(f => !new FileInfo(f).Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Hidden | FileAttributes.System))
```

Comment: Absolutely brilliant, thank you for explaining as well. Will accept in 4 minutes ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You can simplify your code a lot by using DirectoryInfo and FileInfo, eg:

```
var mask= FileAttributes.Hidden | FileAttributes.System;

var di=new DirectoryInfo(sourcePath);
var files=di.EnumerateFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            .Where(fi=>(fi.Attributes & mask) == 0)
            .GroupBy(fi=>fi.DirectoryName);
```

Your original code tried to do a bitwise AND between flags that had no common bits, so it returned 0. As a result, the bitwise AND with `Attributes` also returned 0.

The mask you want to check against is System *or* Hidden ie `FileAttributes.Hidden | FileAttributes.System`. Calculating this in advance simply makes for somewhat cleaner code

Comment: In the Where clause, the bitwise & expression needs to be encased in parentheses, since == has a higher precedence than &, i.e.   `.Where(fi => (fi.Attributes & mask) == 0)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`FileSystemInfo.Attributes.HasFlag`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.attributes(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo( sourcePath );
var files = dir.EnumerateFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Where(f => !f.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Hidden) && !f.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.System))
    .GroupBy(f => f.DirectoryName);
```