# How to filter invisible files in c#?

Tags: c#

I want to find all the invisible files in a folder in C#. I can enumerate the files

```
var files = from file in 
   Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"c:\", "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
select new
{
File = file
};
```

Comment: Wrong it is not a duplicate, even though the code will slightly change the link you posted is to Exclude Hidden files, this post is about Excluding Visible Files. So the concept is the same but the question differs.

Comment: @DonaldJansen - The given duplicate is where the op plagiarised the code from to provide their own answer, how is it not a duplicate?

Comment: Because of this line  
`var filtered = files.Where(f => f.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Hidden));` I understand that he might have recieved that code from that link, or anywhere else and then changed it to fit his needs. But thats just my opinion

Answer (score 1):

You can check for the file attribute using the FileInfo class:

```
            FileInfo f = new FileInfo(path);
            if ((f.Attributes & FileAttributes.Hidden) != 0)
```

Answer (score -2):

From a [previous SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2418311/1451957)

```
DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\");
FileInfo[] files = directory.GetFiles();

var filtered = files.Where(f => f.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Hidden));

foreach (var f in filtered)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(f);
}
```

Comment: If you've found a duplicate then you should link to that duplicate, not take credit and plagiarise it.