# Excluding a directory with specific pattern while using dir.GetDirectories

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I want to exclude folder name '.svn" while using the GetDirectories method

```
DirectoryInfo[] dirs = dir.GetDirectories();
```

I read somewhere that searchPattern parameter for GetDirectories can support only ? and * wildcards and won't support any other regular expression.

I wanted to populate all the folders except ".svn" folder(for example) using DirectoryInfo[] dirs. Is this possible? If not, what are the other alternatives I have?

Comment: Hi, What is .svn ? Hidden folder ? then this is duplicate with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418270/c-sharp-get-a-list-of-files-excluding-those-that-are-hidden

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# - Get a list of files excluding those that are hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418270/c-sharp-get-a-list-of-files-excluding-those-that-are-hidden)

Comment: Thanks. In those examples, we have logic for filtering files. Even though we can use similar logic for getDirectories, I wanted a simple solution for creating a DirectoryInfo[] array with all folders except ".svn".

Comment: .svn is one example. I may need it for a regular folder as well...

Comment: Alternatively you can either look for that particular folder name and remove from the result set, or filter the whole list as it comes.

Comment: Thanks. 
"remove from the results set?" Is it possible to remove from Directoryinfo[] list? If possible great, please let me know (I dont want to re-construct directoryinfo[]). As of now, I had an option to ignore this dir in DirectoryInfo[] while processing (but in several places). But, I wanted a simple solution for this

Comment: Try `DirectoryInfo[] dirs = dir.GetDirectories().Where(x => x.Extension != ".svn").ToArray();`

Comment: That worked.. Thanks..

Comment: I used DirectoryInfo[] dirs = dir.GetDirectories().Where(x => x.Name != ".svn").ToArray(); since it is a folder name (and it required System.Linq; namespace)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer : 
DirectoryInfo[] dirs = dir.GetDirectories().Where(x => x.Name != ".svn").ToArray(); (and it required System.Linq; namespace)

Assuming the following is still applicable :
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1555/mark-a-comment-as-answer-to-a-question

Answer (score 2):

You can use linq methods after GetDirectories method.

```
using System.Linq;
...
...
dir.GetDirectories().Where(d => !d.Name.StartsWith(".")).ToList(); //does not starts with dot.
dir.GetDirectories().Where(d => d.Name != ".svn").ToList(); //does not equal .svn
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, MSDN says (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/f3e2f6e5(v=vs.110).aspx) that search pattern does not support regex. But you can filter the results by regex on the client side. For example:

```
var di = new DirectoryInfo("c:\\");
var dirInfos = di.GetDirectories();
var filtered = from r in dirInfos where !Regex.IsMatch(r.FullName,"$*.svn") select r;
```