# Get all file with Directory.GetFiles(), this get a file but not exist in my folder

Tags: c#, .net

I have a problem with `Directory.GetFiles()`. I get all file with it, but I have a file doesn't not exist in my folder (file like `~$temp.docx`), so what's that problem ?

This is my code. Thanks

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath(path), "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Comment: Note that the `~$temp.docx` file might have its "hidden" and/or "system file" attribute set, hiding it from normal view in the file explorer...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# - Get a list of files excluding those that are hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418270/c-sharp-get-a-list-of-files-excluding-those-that-are-hidden)

Answer (score 2):

`~$temp.docx` is a hidden file.  If you dont need any of the hidden files in a folder you could just exclude them.  Which is discussed in this thread: [C# - Get a list of files excluding those that are hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418270/c-sharp-get-a-list-of-files-excluding-those-that-are-hidden)

Answer (score 0):

I'd wager that there IS a file like that in your directory, but you can's see it with File Explorer.  That kind of file is a hidden file that is created when you have a word document open in Microsoft Word.  Windows File Explorer doesn't show those files by default when you open up a folder and look at the files.  You need to go to View -> Options -> Advanced Settings -> Show Hidden Files and set it to show hidden files.  Then you'll see that file with File Explorer as well as your C# code.