# getFiles() not folders

Tags: javascript, photoshop-script, getfiles

I've got several files in a temporary folder. I can load them into Photoshop with scripting the following:

```
  var sourceFolder = Folder("C:\\temp");
  if (sourceFolder != null)
  {
     var fileList = sourceFolder.getFiles();
  }
```

This is all good, but how do I ignore directories (such as C:\temp\waffles) that might also be in there also.

I understand that I could do a check for valid image extensions and then add them to a new filelist array and then load that. I don't think the search option TopDirectoryOnly is valid here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exclude certain file extensions when get files from a directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/755166/exclude-certain-file-extensions-when-get-files-from-a-directory)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since getFiles() "[Returns an array of File and Folder objects](https://wwwimages2.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/products/indesign/pdfs/JavaScriptToolsGuide_CS5.pdf#G5.1774297)" You will need to iterate over each of the objects returned and test to see what kind of object it is. From Adobe's Creative Suite 5 [Javacript Tools Guide](https://wwwimages2.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/products/indesign/pdfs/JavaScriptToolsGuide_CS5.pdf)

> There are several ways to distinguish between a File and a Folder object. For example:
>
>
> `if (f instanceof File)...
>
> if (typeof f.open == "undefined")... //Folders do not open.`

Comment: Thanks Rich. That's exactly what I was after!

Answer (score 0):

If I use this when getting folder or files, I avoid write `if()` later:

```
var fileList = sourceFolder.getFiles(function(f) { return f instanceof File; });
```

The same when getting only folders:

```
var fileList = sourceFolder.getFiles(function(f) { return f instanceof Folder; });
```

However it is recommended to use the `getFiles` function as less as possible because the code will run faster.

I also use `RegExp` objects to pick only specific sub-folders in a folder.

For example, if I set a regular expression like the '**regthis**' var as below. The folders collected with 'getFiles' will be the one that its name:
A) Must have '12345678' at the end or a uppercase letter before '12345678';
B) Must also have one of the 2 characters ('_' or a 'c') before A;
C) Must have 1 lowercase letter 'a-v' before B+A;
D) Must not have 'x' or 'y' or 'z' before C+B+A;

```
var ID_ = '12345678';
var regthis = new RegExp( '([^x-z]{1}[a-v]{1}[_|c]{1})([A-Z]?'+ID_+'?)$','i');
var sameIDfolder = Folder(myFolder).getFiles(regthis);
```