# Excluded several extension c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, folderbrowserdialog

How can I exclude all `.txt` file and doc file in a folder?

I am able to get all the file but unable to exclude `.txt` file and `.doc` files.

```
foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(@readpath))
            {
                List<string> list = new List<string>();
                list.Add(f);

                for (listcount = 0; listcount < list.Count; listcount++)
                {
                    path2 = list[listcount];
                    creationdate = File.GetCreationTime(path2);
                    modidate = File.GetLastWriteTime(path2);

                }
                chkchecksum();
            }
```

Comment: I think this has been asked before, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/755166/exclude-certain-file-extensions-when-get-files-from-a-directory , if not please explain what else you need =)

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(@readpath))
```

With

```
foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(@readpath).Where(f => !(f.EndsWith(".doc", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && !f.EndsWith(".txt", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))))
```