# Search for interface in all assemblies of bin

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

How can I scan all assemblies located in the bin directory and retrieve all types implementing an interface?

Comment: any of these answers answer your question?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can find them easily using Reflection and a LINQ query

```
var type = typeof(IRyuDice);
var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().ToList()
    .SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes())
    .Where(t => type.IsAssignableFrom(t));
```

`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies` returns a `System.Reflection.Assembly[]` collection. Then you select all Types in that Assembly and check if your interface is used by that type.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.getassemblies.aspx

Comment: I don't think this answers the question as it will only process assemblies that are LOADED in the CurrentDomain, not those present but as-yet  unused in the bin directory.

There is an answer here that might help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288288/how-to-load-all-assemblies-from-within-your-bin-directory

Answer (score 2):

My answer might be too obvious but I'll give it a shot...

You need to take a look at [DirectoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx) to get every file (*.dll) of the directory and the use [reflection](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Development-Class/Usingreflectiontogetinformationaboutanassem) in order to digg into them...

Does that answer your question or do you want to know the actual implementation?