# How to preload all the assemblies?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, user-interface

I have a simple application which performs a search in the user's computer and then display's the results. I have a function `search` which searches for the files in the computer and a  function `DisplayForm` which then display's the form containing the results. The results are displayed inside a `ListBox`.
Search function is called inside a `BackgroundWorker` and the `DisplayFunction` is called when the `BackgroundWorker` completes. 
The problem that I am facing is thate the first time the search function is called just after computer reboot , although the search function takes very less time (1 second or so), the time taken to display the form takes too long.(10 seconds or so).
Correct me if I am wrong,
 based on what I have googled and read, I think the problem is that as soon as the `BackgroundWorker` completes, Assemblies required for `DisplayForm` start loading, which takes considerable time, and after that the form containing the search results is displayed.
I think the solution for the problem is that I can preload all the assemblies, so that when the `DisplayForm` function is called, there is not time wasted in loading the assemblies. 
I am completely new to this stuff, and don't have any clue on how to do it. 
I know about the `System.Reflection.Assembly.Load()` function, but I am unable to find "How to use it". So, basically I need help with using the `Assembly.Load()` function.
Below I am posting the code for `DisplayForm` function. Please have a look at it.

```
    private void DisplayForm()
    {
        Label LabelMessage = new Label();
        LabelMessage.Text = "There are a total of " + ReaderClass.SearchList.Count.ToString() + " files and folders found with the given name. ";
        LabelMessage.Parent = SearchForm;
        LabelMessage.Left = 300;
        LabelMessage.Top = 0;
        LabelMessage.Size = new Size(800, 75);
        LabelMessage.Font = new Font("Impact", 20);
        LabelMessage.Show();
        SearchForm.Controls.Add(LabelMessage);
        SearchForm.AutoScroll = true;
        ResultListBox.Parent = SearchForm;
        ResultListBox.DataSource = null;
        ResultListBox.DataSource = ReaderClass.SearchList;
        ResultListBox.Width = 1340;
        ResultListBox.Height = 1300;
        ResultListBox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
        ResultListBox.ScrollAlwaysVisible = true;
        ResultListBox.Left = 0;
        ResultListBox.Top = 100;
        ResultListBox.DoubleClick += OpenFile;
        ResultListBox.KeyDown += OpenFileKey;
        ResultListBox.Font = new Font("Arial", 14, FontStyle.Regular);
        notifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = "Search Completed. It took " + (ReaderClass.SearchTime.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000.0).ToString() + " to complete the search. ";
        notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(2000);
        if (ReaderClass.SearchList.Count != 0)
        {
            ResultListBox.DataSource = ReaderClass.SearchList;
            SearchForm.ShowDialog();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Sorry, we couldn't find anything with this name.", "No Results", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }
        ReaderClass.SearchList.Clear();
        LabelMessage.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: So the second time a user search, with different query, the result is displayed much more quickly?

Comment: Yes, very very quickly. In fact, the search query doesn't matter at all here.!

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't matter?

Comment: What I mean is that the time taken to display the form overrules the time taken by search function. for ex if query A took 1 second to search and query B took 3 seconds to search ,the form will be displayed in 10 seconds (approx) when    running first time after reeboot,

Comment: So as long as the user doesn't reboot, any query except the first will run fast? And the results are correct? Why not simply trigger a dummy search at the first launch and hardcode a special query that won't be displayed?

Comment: Yes, any query other than the first will run fast, I used this idea, but the problem is "displaying", if I don't display the results of dummy search , the problem remains  so , I have to display the results if I do dummy search which is not possible. If I don't display the results, the problem remains as it is. `Search` functions takes same time whether you run it after startup or subsequent times.

Comment: Even if you set the Visible property to false? The way I see it you overload the DisplayForm constructor to accept a boolean parameter, and when it's set to true, the first thing it does is setting the Visible parameter to false. THEN, the Form_Load event would check if it's visible, and would close itself if it's not visible

Comment: @Martheen Thanks, I will try it. It might solve the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to load all assemblies from within your /bin directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288288/how-to-load-all-assemblies-from-within-your-bin-directory)