# Getting error with mysql version 6.9.5 on server

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, web-hosting

Here problem is that I have install `Mysql 6.9.5` on my local machine and it is working fine on local machine but after hosting on live server I am getting error as below.

**Error Message**

`Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.9.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

**Web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="MySql.Data, Version=6.9.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=C5687FC88969C44D"/>
        <add assembly="MySql.Web, Version=6.9.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=C5687FC88969C44D"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime/>
  </system.web>

  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="MySql.Data" publicKeyToken="C5687FC88969C44D" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="5.5.32" newVersion="6.9.5.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>

  <appSettings>        
    <add key="karmadbeConnection" value="server=*.*.*.*;User ID=*;Password=*;database=*;persist security info=False"/>       
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

**Server Description**

There is `mysql 5.5.32`version is installed on `easycgi` server. I hope there is version problem with server hosting. but not getting any solution.

if somebody have any solution or suggestion then it will be aceptable Thanks in advance.

Comment: is _mysql.data.dll_ located in bin folder?

Comment: yes mysql.data.dll it is

Answer (score 0):

to me it seems like problem with versions. Your code is saying "I want to use the 6.9.5" and server responds: "Ohh noo, you little website, I have only  5.5.32". Contact someone from the hosting company.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest listing all the loaded assemblies using the code below

```
Assembly[] asms = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
foreach (Assembly asm in asms)
{
    Response.Write(asm.FullName  + "<br/>");
}
```

If you verify that the *mysql.data.dll* is located in *bin* folder, perhaps for some reason it's trying to use an older version loaded from *GAC*.

You can also try removing

```
<add assembly="MySql.Data, Version=6.9.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=C5687FC88969C44D"/>
```

from web.config and see what happens.

**EDIT**

You might also want to check out [how to load all assemblies from within your /bin directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288288/how-to-load-all-assemblies-from-within-your-bin-directory).

Answer (score 0):

Put MySql  Connector DLLS In Bin File Or ask your Provide Top install .net Connector

1. MySql.Data
2. MySql.Data.Entity
3. MySql.Web

if Required Then Others Too
You Can Find Them

C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net 6.9.5\Assemblies\v4.0