# A easier way to add in 50pictures?

Tags: c#

So i got this piece of code

```
namespace kortspel
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form

    {

        ArrayList kortlek = new ArrayList();
        Image c1 = new Bitmap("C:/Users/Mert95/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/kortspel/Spelkort/c1.png");
```

And i don't want to add in 50pictures with a unique name such as Image c2 = blablabla.

Some people have said i need to create a loop, to add in these 50pictures, so is there a easier way instead of adding in 50 Images in the array?

Comment: Do they all reside in one directory; moreover, do they have predictable names (e.g. c1, c2, c3) or are the the only thing residing in a single directory?

Comment: Possible dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953254/cgetting-all-image-files-in-folder

Comment: Where are you adding them to? Also, don't use an `ArrayList` unless you're using .NET 1.1. Use a `List<Image>` or whatever you're putting into the list.

Comment: Define Array List of type `Image`, then get all files from directory that are images and in the loop declare them as `Image` and add to ArrayList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Directory.GetFiles(string path, string searchPattern)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx) to get an array of all the files in a directory matching a given pattern.
Then, just iterate over the files in a loop like this:

```
string path = "C:/Users/Mert95/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/kortspel/Spelkort/";
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.png");
List<Bitmap> images = new List<Bitmap>();
foreach (var file in files)
{
    images.Add(new Bitmap(file);
}
```

Comment: If you're using .NET 4.0 or above, try [`Directory.EnumerateFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles.aspx) instead. No need to read all the file names into memory at once.

Comment: You can also do this with linq, var files = Directory.GetFiles("path").Where(x => x.Contains("png"));

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Linq is a good way.

```
string path = @"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures";
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.jpg");
var result = from jpeg in files.AsEnumerable()
             select Image.FromFile(jpeg);
```