# Download link for Images within a folder, or download link for direct images

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, image-processing

I am wanting to create a download link which will download a folder full of images based on the link directory, or create multiple links which will toggle a download of single images.

I have found the code below, however, this only seems to work on images which are local, not from a external url which is where I store my images, does anyone have any suggestions?

```
<a href="/path/to/image" download>
    <img src="/path/to/image" />
</a>
```

Comment: You cannot download a folder with a single link. You need to create a zip-archive and send that to the client. Or create a download link per file, but that would mean that the user has to click x links manually.

Comment: Thanks, I can have buttons for each images then, to download each one individually on each click, do you know of a way to do this with external link paths @VDWWD

Comment: Browsers will not ask to download images by default..

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `Directory.GetFiles` and bind the files directly to a Repeater Control.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>

        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Target="_blank"
            NavigateUrl='<%# "/images/" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Container.DataItem.ToString()) %>'>
            <%# System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Container.DataItem.ToString()) %>
        </asp:HyperLink>

        <br />

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Then in code behind you bind the files to the Repeater

```
Repeater1.DataSource = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/images/"), "*.jpg");
Repeater1.DataBind();
```

See this link for more complex filter option for getting all the image files from a folder: [C#:Getting all image files in folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953254/cgetting-all-image-files-in-folder)

Answer (score 0):

```
<a download="yourfilename.jpg" href="http://www.example.com/path/to/image.jpg" title="Image title">
    <img alt="Image title" src="http://www.example.com/path/to/image.jpg">
</a>
```

This `download` attribute might not be supported by all modern browsers yet.. [check the tables](https://caniuse.com/#feat=download). Safari at this point will not work for example.

Alternatively you can opt to cook your own download script. Check [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7238099/1397220) for an example with PHP.