# How to create a collection of images from a directory

Tags: c#

I'm looking for how to create a collection of images from a directory and then instantiate all the images dynamically.

Actually I instantiate my images as follows:

```
    private BitmapSource orange = BitmapUtil.FromImages("orange.png");
    private BitmapSource lemon = BitmapUtil.FromImages("lemon.png");
    private BitmapSource apple = BitmapUtil.FromImages("apple.png");
```

But the problem is that, let's say someone add new fruits in the directory that contains all these images of fruits. I want to instantiate all of these fruits dynamically so when we run the program, it checks for all the images in the folder `/fruits/...` and then create this list of elements.

Edit:
I want to do this using BitmapSource and BitmalUtil.FromImages because I still want to manipulate those images within a method. I don't want to store them randomly in a list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C#:Getting all image files in folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953254/cgetting-all-image-files-in-folder)

Comment: Do you mean `Directory.GetFiles`?

Comment: Well first off, you need to actually store these in a collection, rather than separate private fields.

Comment: It's not what i'm looking for...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
List<BitmapSource> images = new List();
foreach (var filePath in Directory.GetFiles("Fruit"))
{
    images.Add(BitmapUtil.FromImages(filePath));
}
```

You may as well use LINQ:

```
var images = Directory.EnumerateFiles("Fruit")
    .Select(f => BitmapUtil.FromImage(f))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: `EnumerateFiles` (instead of `GetFiles`) is a better choice: we start creating images before obtaining all the files.