# Get files from directory with pattern

Tags: c#, .net, file, directory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you call Directory.GetFiles() with multiple filters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163162/can-you-call-directory-getfiles-with-multiple-filters)

Does it possible to get for ex. `.c` and `.h`files from directory. Usage of `Directory.GetFiles("C:\", ".c;.h");` does not work. It's too bad to invoke `Directory.GetFiles(...);` twice.. :(

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

its not possible to specify multiple filters in single GetFiles() method call. You can find alternatives [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163162/can-you-call-directory-getfiles-with-multiple-filters)

Answer (score 6):

If you're using .NET 4.0, I'd go with [`Directory.EnumerateFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383458.aspx):

```
var files = from f in Directory.EnumerateFiles("C:\\")
            where f.EndsWith(".c") || f.EndsWith(".h")
            select f;
```

Comment: @Yuriy: The only thing .NET 4.0 there is the use of `Directory.EnumerateFiles()`.  Change it to `Directory.GetFiles()` and it should work just as fine.

Comment: @Jeff M: I could be wrong, but I'm pretty sure @Yuriy wants to avoid calling `GetFiles()` to dodge the cost of populating a (potentially) huge `string[]` array.

Comment: If that were the case, then getting all files then filtering wouldn't be the best way to handle this then.  ;)  I figured Yuriy would like to apply these filters in a single call rather than writing two separate calls by hand which seems reasonable based on the answer that was chosen.

Comment: @Jeff: True -- but it'd still be cheaper (memory-wise) than `GetFiles()`, and would start returning values right away (without having to fetch all files first). But you're right; judging from the accepted answer, it seems the OP wasn't too concerned about that, actually.

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like this:

```
 var query = from p in Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\").AsEnumerable()
                    where p.Contains(".c")
                    || p.Contains(".h")
                    select p;
```

Comment: No reason to call AsEnumerable here. GetFiles will have already filled the entire array.

Answer (score 1):

For .Net 3.5.

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetFiles(
     string basePath, 
     params string[] searchPatterns)
{
    if (searchPatterns == null || searchPatterns.Length == 0)
    {
        return Directory.GetFiles(basePath);
    }

    return Enumerable.SelectMany(searchPatterns, 
                         p => Directory.GetFiles(basePath, p));
}
```

Usage:

```
GetFiles(@"c:\", "*.c", "*.h");
```

you probably want to add some validation

Answer (score 0):

See [How to get files with multiple extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527203/getfiles-with-multiple-extentions/3527717#3527717) using extension methods.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some useful helper functions to simulate having multiple filters:

```
// .NET 4.0 friendly
public static IEnumerable<string> EnumerateFiles(string path, params string[] filters)
{
    return filters.Length == 0
        ? Directory.EnumerateFiles(path)
        : filters.SelectMany(filter => Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, filter));
}

// .NET 3.5 friendly
public static IEnumerable<string> GetFiles(string path, params string[] filters)
{
    return filters.Length == 0
        ? Directory.GetFiles(path)
        : filters.SelectMany(filter => Directory.GetFiles(path, filter));
}
```