# c# IIllegal Characters in Path

Tags: c#, .net, mscorlib, illegal-characters

I don't see what is wrong about the below code. It throws an error at Line 4

```
private void ProcessCsvsReplaceNullsWithSpaces()
{
    string server = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["RapServer"];
    string importDir = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["importDir"];
    string fileName = server + @"\" + importDir + "\\EMIR_VU_E_*.csv";
    string replacenull = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
    replacenull = replacenull.Replace("null", "");
    File.WriteAllText(fileName, replacenull);
}
```

Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Illegal characters in path.

Comment: What is contents of `ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["RapServer"];` and  `ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["importDir"];` ?

Comment: The asterisk is not a valid character in a filename used by ReadAllText, it is a wildcard used to match multiple files If you want to read multiple files you will need to use the directory methods to get a list of matching files & read them one by one.

Comment: A single filename may not contain a `*`

Comment: If you are facing this kind of problems, just try to create file or folder with that name you want to create.

Comment: Try to create a file with *. You won't be allowed.

Comment: Also note that .Newt provides a method to join parts of file path & filename without using hard coded separators [Path.Combine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx) or [this version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd784047(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Note that if you want to match a pattern when retrieving file(s), there's a solution for that. See, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775828/get-files-from-directory-with-pattern

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always check your path, whether it contains invalid path characters.
Try iterating with the method `Path.GetInvalidPathChars`.

[See the documentation of msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.path.getinvalidpathchars(v=vs.110).aspx)

This lists all invalid characters. Now you can iterate your path to check if there are any chars matching that list

```
bool containsInvalidChars = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filepath) 
        && filepath.IndexOfAny(System.IO.Path.GetInvalidPathChars()) >= 0);
```

if this is true, you got an invalid char in your path

As a few others mentioned: your filename must not contain a `*` character

You also need to check, whether your filename contains invalid characters:

This is the method: `System.IO.Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()`

Here you find the `*`:

[image]