# Get path to all images in specified directory

Tags: image, path, directory

how do I find a path to all image files with bmp extension from specified folder. If I want to get a paths for example for all Directories inside the other I use simply:

```
Directory.GetDirectories(path);
```

I am looking for a method simular to the one above.

Oh Apology for that, I am using C#

Comment: Do we need to guess the programming language you are using?..

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4124254/want-to-list-all-image-files-in-a-folder-using-c-sharp

Comment: I dont understand the code from the guy 'Noring'(3rd from the end). What dose 'from' 'in' 'where' and 'select' syntax means?