# Passing multiple extensions to the System.IO.Directory.GetFiles method

Tags: c#, io, directory, getfiles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [GetFiles with multiple extentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527203/getfiles-with-multiple-extentions)

How can I specify multiple extensions for the System.IO.Directory.GetFiles method?

I have tried.

```
string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.jpg *.png");
```

and

```
string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.jpg, *.png");
```

to no success.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Thank you. Sorry about that I did look.

Answer (score 2):

You may checkout the [following blog post](http://shaunedonohue.blogspot.com/2007/03/getting-multiple-file-extensions-with.html).