# Directory.getfiles() with Multiple Wild Cards or Filters Alternative in c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, file, directory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [GetFiles with multiple extentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527203/getfiles-with-multiple-extentions)

I want to use a Multiple filter eg:.mp3,.jpg to retrieve the string array of the files of these types.But unfortunately Directory.getfiles() does not provide this functionality efficiently.

I know this question has been asked many times over here but I have just found out an article at http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-FAQ/Multiple-Filters-Directory.GetFiles-Method.aspx

which gives the following function for tackling this problem

```
public string[] getFiles(string SourceFolder, string Filter,
 System.IO.SearchOption searchOption)
{
 // ArrayList will hold all file names
ArrayList alFiles = new ArrayList();

 // Create an array of filter string
 string[] MultipleFilters = Filter.Split('|');

 // for each filter find mathing file names
 foreach (string FileFilter in MultipleFilters)
 {
  // add found file names to array list
  alFiles.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(SourceFolder, FileFilter, searchOption));
 }

 // returns string array of relevant file names
 return (string[])alFiles.ToArray(typeof(string));
}
```

I want to know if this method is efficient.If a drive eg:C:\ is specified will this method search the entire drive?
Can anyone suggest me a method to add subfolder searching to this method explicitly

Answer (score 0):

You also may ran LINQ queries on total result to get the files you want and *union* the results