# Oring file extensions in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

```
For Each File As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(Line, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, "*.txt|*.docx")

Next
```

is it right to OR extensions this way? 
I just need to get the `txt` and `docx` files

Comment: Same as this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527203/getfiles-with-multiple-extentions

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you call Directory.GetFiles() with multiple filters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/163162/can-you-call-directory-getfiles-with-multiple-filters)

Comment: Not a duplicate, My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles accepts a string array for wildcards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at this [MSDN Forum Post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressvb/thread/ab4b5290-49db-40c9-9e12-f2ab37db7d3b/) it suggests that using an array to hold the file extensions like this will work. Using an Or statement like you have will give you an error.

```
Dim line As String = "C:\Temp"
Dim extension(1) As String
extension(0) = "*.txt"
extension(1) = "*.docx"

For Each File As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(Line, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, extension)

Next
```

Answer (score -2):

```
    Dim extension As New List(Of String)
    extension.Add("*.avi")
    extension.Add("*.mkv")
    extension.Add("*.wmv")
    extension.Add("*.mp4")
```

For Each F In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles("c:\yourPath", FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories, extension.ToArray)

' do it

next