# Check if folder contains files with certain extensions

Tags: c#

I have other C# code that drops a call recording file into the folder c:\Recordings

Each file has the extension of .wma

I'd like to be able to check the folder every 5 minutes. If the folder contains a file ending in .wma i'd like to execute some code.

If the folder does not contain a file with the .wma extension, i'd like the code to pause for 5 minutes and then re-check (infinitely).

i've started with the following the check if the folder has any files in it at all, but when I run it, it always reports the folder contains files, even though it does not.

```
string dirPath = @"c:\recordings\";
        if (Directory.GetFiles(dirPath).Length == 0)
        {
            NewRecordingExists = true;
            Console.WriteLine("New Recording exists");
        }
        else
        {
            NewRecordingExists = false;
            Console.WriteLine("No New Recording exists");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(300000);
        }
```

Comment: `Directory.GetFiles(dirPath, "*.wma").Length==0` to filter out every other file except wma extensions.
You can look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx which will probably serve your purpose

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
if (Directory.GetFiles(dirPath).Length == 0)
```

This is checking if there are no files... then you are reporting `"New Recording exists"`. I think you just have your logic the wrong way around. `else` is where it means you have found some files.

In addition, if you want to check for just `*.wma` files then you can use [the `GetFiles` overload that takes a search pattern parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), for example:

```
if (Directory.GetFiles(dirPath, "*.wma").Length == 0)
{
    //NO matching *.wma files
}
else
{
    //has matching *.wma files
}
```

---

**SIDE NOTE**: You may be interested in the [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), this would enable you to monitor your recordings folder for changes (including when files are added). This would eliminate your requirement to poll every 5 minutes, and you get near-instant execution when the file is added, as opposed to waiting for the 5 minute interval to tick over

Comment: How can I check for more than 2 extensions for example, .xls and .xlsx

Comment: @wearybands: By searching for [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527203/getfiles-with-multiple-extentions)

Answer (score 2):

First of all your logic is reversed! ;)
here is you correct code:

```
        bool NewRecordingExists;
        string dirPath = @"c:\recordings\";
        string[] fileNames = Directory.GetFiles(dirPath, "*.wma", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
        if (fileNames.Length != 0)
        {
            NewRecordingExists = true;
            foreach (string fileName in fileNames)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("New Recording exists: {0}", fileName);
                /*  do you process for each file here */
            }
        }
        else
        {
            NewRecordingExists = false;
            Console.WriteLine("No New Recording exists");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(300000);
        }
```

Although, i recommend using `System.Timers.Timer` class for you application!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `GetFiles` if you're going to throw the result away.
Use an enumeration so you can exit early:

```
Directory.EnumerateFiles(Folder, "*.wma", SearchOption.AllDirectories).FirstOrDefault() != null
```