# Search a specific file in a folder C#

Tags: c#

I have some files that name are `ABC-randomcode.zip`,`ABC-randomcode.mov` and etc.

I use this code to find all file which started by `ABC` but it does not work!

```
var textFiles = Directory.GetFiles("E:\\000", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(s => s.StartsWith("foldername-"));
```

[its](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527203/getfiles-with-multiple-extensions) not my problem . My target is to select some file that starts with a unique string like `ABC`.

Comment: _foldername-_ != _ABC_

Comment: Directory.GetFiles will return full paths, so it'll return a bunch of `"E:\000\..."`. None of those strings will start with `"foldername-"`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GetFiles with multiple extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527203/getfiles-with-multiple-extensions)

Comment: @Marco its not my problem . My target is to select some file that starts with a unique string like ABC.

Comment: Well, how about `Directory.GetFiles("...", "ABC*.*")` then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `foldername-` to your search pattern:

```
var textFiles = Directory.GetFiles("E:\\000", "foldername-*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

From docs:

> The search string to match against the names of files in path. This parameter can contain a combination of valid literal path and wildcard (* and ?) characters, but it doesn't support regular expressions.

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=netframework-4.8)