# Directory.GetFiles of certain extension

Tags: c#, linq, directory, getfiles

Is there a way to simplify this linq expression, or is there a better way of doing this?

```
Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
         .Where(s => s.EndsWith(".jpg", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
                     s.EndsWith(".gif", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
                     s.EndsWith(".png", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
                     ...);
```

Basically I want to return all files of a certain extension. Unfortunately, this method isn't very flexible. I'd rather be able to add extensions to a list and have Directory.GetFiles return those extensions. Is that possible?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/163162/can-you-call-directory-getfiles-with-multiple-filters

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you call Directory.GetFiles() with multiple filters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163162/can-you-call-directory-getfiles-with-multiple-filters)

Answer (score 127, accepted):

If you would like to do your filtering in LINQ, you can do it like this:

```
var ext = new List<string> { "jpg", "gif", "png" };
var myFiles = Directory
    .EnumerateFiles(dir, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Where(s => ext.Contains(Path.GetExtension(s).TrimStart(".").ToLowerInvariant()));
```

Now `ext` contains a list of allowed extensions; you can add or remove items from it as necessary for flexible filtering.

Comment: I can perform tests, but do you know which one would be more efficient?

Comment: Interesting that it works... From the documentation on `GetFiles`, it doesn't seem like it would accept the `|` like you would expect from a regex. The docs say it only recognizes `*` and `?`, but hey, if it works, it works =)

Comment: Note: This doesn't seem to work on Win7 x64 running .NET 4.5. Throws `Illegal characters in path` due to the pipe.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Never mind, I misinterpreted [a piece of code in a post on Microsoft's web site](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxbcl/thread/b0c31115-f6f0-4de5-a62d-d766a855d4d1), where a similarly-named method has been interpreting the pipes internally. I removed the non-working part of the solution (and SSL checked only the first one).

Comment: Note for the passerby: you might get a performance boost out of the newer .NET 4.0 `Directory.EnumerateFiles` as mentioned in answer by @nekizalb

Answer (score 34):

Doesn't the [`Directory.GetFiles(String, String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx) overload already do that? You would just do `Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories)`

If you want to put them in a list, then just replace the `"*.jpg"` with a variable that iterates over a list and aggregate the results into an overall result set. Much clearer than individually specifying them. =)

Something like...

```
foreach(String fileExtension in extensionList){
    foreach(String file in Directory.GetFiles(dir, fileExtension, SearchOption.AllDirectories)){
        allFiles.Add(file);
    }
}
```

For .NET 4+: if your directories are large, using [`EnumerateFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413379.aspx) instead of `GetFiles` can potentially be more efficient

Comment: Please be aware of the fact that while using wildcard * there is always chance that you can mess up the intended logic . For instance you have two files Test1.xls and Test2.xlsx and if you use filter *.xls to filter out xls file , Directory.GetFiles ** returns both xls as well as xlsx files **. [Read MSDN for more info]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: effectively, xls and xlsx are the same file that modern day Excel can read?

Comment: @ina It's not an issue for Excel, it's an issue for other systems that try to read Excel data. But yes it's an exceedingly rare edge case.

Answer (score 13):

I would have done using just a single line like:

```
List<string> imageFiles = Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(file => new string[] { ".jpg", ".gif", ".png" }.Contains(Path.GetExtension(file))).ToList();
```

Comment: This works, of course, but the lambda expression you pass to `.Where()` will create one `string[]` [every time it's invoked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39106109/creating-a-constant-but-local-array); that is, for every file under `dir`.  If `dir` is, say, `@"C:\"` then this could potentially create tens or hundreds of thousands of short-lived "garbage" arrays.  I definitely think it'd be worth it to define your array outside of `.Where()`, even if it means having to write that dreaded second line of code.