# Display filetype from directory in ASP.NET MVC 4 Project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I currently learning about ASP.NET MVC 4.

I want to display `.cs` and `.cpp` files located in a directory on the web page. But somehow I get exception for multiple file type display.

Below line of code gives exception:

```
string pattern ="*.cs|*.cpp";
```

Till now I wrote below code:

```
public ActionResult Contact()
{
    string pattern = "*.cs";
    //string pattern ="*.cs|*.cpp";  // this line does not work  
    ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";
    DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"f:\");
    List<string> filenames = dirInfo.GetFiles(pattern).Select(i => i.Name).ToList();
    ViewBag.data = filenames;
    return View(filenames);
}
```

The View code looks like:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Contact";
}
<hgroup class="title">
    <h1>@ViewBag.Title.</h1>
    <h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
</hgroup>
<table bgcolor="#00FF00">
    @foreach (var item in (List<string>)ViewBag.data)
    {
        <tr>
            <th>@item   <br></th>

        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Comment: So what's going wrong? Are you getting an error?

Comment: I get exception when I write 'string pattern ="(asterisk).cs|(asterisk).cpp"' . It works only for one file type. For multiple I get an exception

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/163220/2474175) or even [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13301088/2474175).

Comment: This isn't Classic ASP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to need to do something like this:

```
        string pattern = "*.cs";
        ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";
        DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"f:\");
        List<string> filenames = new List<string>();
        foreach (FileInfo f in dirInfo.GetFiles(pattern))
        {
            filenames.Add(f.Name);  //or f.FullName to include path
        }
        pattern = "*.cpp";
        foreach (string f in dirInfo.GetFiles(pattern))
        {
            filenames.Add(f);
        }

        ViewBag.data = filenames;
        return View(filenames);
```

or, something like this:

```
        public ActionResult Contact()
    {

        string pattern = "*.cs|*.cpp";
        ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";
        DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"f:\");
        List<string> filenames = new List<string>();
        string[] temp = pattern.Split('|');
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.Length; i++)
        {
            filenames.AddRange(GetFiles(temp[i]));
        }
        ViewBag.data = filenames;
        return View(filenames);
    }

    public List<string> GetFiles(string pattern) {
        DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"f:\");
        List<string> filenames = new List<string>();
        foreach (FileInfo f in dirInfo.GetFiles(pattern))
        {
            filenames.Add(f.Name);  //or f.FullName to include path
        }
        return filenames;
    }
```

The nice thing about that, is that you'll have an opportunity to sort, and filter the list further before returning it to your view.

Comment: the first method that you have mentioned gives error as line ' foreach (string f in dirInfo.GetFiles(pattern))'  : I get red squiggly under the 'foreach'

Comment: It says cannot convert System.IO.FileInfo to 'string'

Comment: That was more of an example than anything else.  You get back a File object, and File.Name would be the string you're after..

Comment: I updated the code to use FileInfo instead of String.  The above code should now run without issues.

Answer (score 0):

`DirectoryInfo.GetFiles(pattern)` only allows a single pattern. It is not like the filter you set when creating a common dialog.

If you want multiple patterns, you can create your own extension method, there are some examples here:: [GetFiles with multiple extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527203/getfiles-with-multiple-extentions)