# How to convert files to base 64

Tags: c#, .net

I am new to C# and I'm really having a trouble on finding a way to convert files(doc, xlsx, jpg, png, etc.) to base64.

So far, what I got is a way to retrieve the path using `Directory.GetFiles()`....but this is not the result I was expecting.

What I expected it to do is get the data of the files(not the path) and convert it to base64 so that I can display it on my front-end.

Any idea?

Comment: Please google a bit more and start searcing on stackoverflow and if you have a specific problem you can post that here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25919387/converting-file-into-base64string-and-back-again

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13301053/directory-getfiles-of-certain-extension

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting file into Base64String and back again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25919387/converting-file-into-base64string-and-back-again)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
foreach (string filePath in  Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\directory"))
        {
            Byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
            String file = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
        }
```