# Can System.IO.Directory.GetFiles() search with multiple search strings?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005, .net-2.0

I want to search for all files ending `.vcproj` or `.sln` in a directory. It's not clear to me from the docs if `searchPattern` can specify multiple filters or if I'd have to run separate searches.

Comment: here's a link to similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/163162/can-you-call-directory-getfiles-with-multiple-filters

Comment: @Dhawalk: Nice use of LINQ in the accepted answer of that question, though LINQ is not available in a .NET 2.0 environment.

Comment: my bad. I missed that.... thanks

Comment: @Dhawalk: Still a good comment, because others that find this question might not be constrained to .NET 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can only specify one filter.

You can add the result of each search to a `HashSet<string>` to get a unique list of files matching both searches.  A `List<string>` would not work in edge cases where two different wildcard search patterns can match the same file.

UPDATE

`HashSet<T>` is only available in .NET 3.5 and later. Since you are using 2.0, you could use a `List<T>`, but you should check if each item already exists before adding it.

Answer (score 1):

For [`GetFiles()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getfiles.aspx) you can use 1 filter option. You shoul get them separately.

```
string[] file1 = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.vcproj");
string[] file2 = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.sln ");
```