# How can Directory.Getfiles() multi searchpattern filters c#

Tags: c#, directory, getfiles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you call Directory.GetFiles() with multiple filters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163162/can-you-call-directory-getfiles-with-multiple-filters)

I have a string array:

```
string[] pattern={"*.jpg","*.txt","*.asp","*.css","*.cs",.....};
```

this string pattern

```
string[] dizin = Directory.GetFiles("c:\veri",pattern);
```

How dizin variable C:\veri directories under the directory of files assign?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use something like this

```
string[] extensions = { "jpg", "txt", "asp", "css", "cs", "xml" };

string[] dizin = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\s\sent", "*.*")
    .Where(f => extensions.Contains(f.Split('.').Last().ToLower())).ToArray();
```

Or use `FileInfo.Extension` bit safer than `String.Split` but may be slower

```
string[] extensions = { ".jpg", ".txt", ".asp", ".css", ".cs", ".xml" };

string[] dizin = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\s\sent", "*.*")
    .Where(f => extensions.Contains(new FileInfo(f).Extension.ToLower())).ToArray();
```

Or as **juharr** mentioned you can also use `System.IO.Path.GetExtension`

```
string[] extensions = { ".jpg", ".txt", ".asp", ".css", ".cs", ".xml" };

string[] dizin = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\s\sent", "*.*")
    .Where(f => extensions.Contains(System.IO.Path.GetExtension(f).ToLower())).ToArray();
```

Comment: Or use `Path.GetExtension`

Comment: yep, there is lots of ways, just whatever works best for OP, Its a bit of a shame `Directory.GetFiles` does not allow mutiple extensions

Answer (score 2):

You have different alternatives.

```
String[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(s => s.ToLower().EndsWith(".jpg") || s.ToLower().EndsWith(".txt") || s.ToLower().EndsWith(".asp"));
```

Or:

```
String[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path).Where(file => Regex.IsMatch(file, @"^.+\.(jpg|txt|asp)$"));
```

Or (if you don't use Linq extensions):

```
List<String> files = new List<String>();
String[] extensions = new String[] { "*.jpg", "*.txt", "*.asp" };

foreach (String extension in extensions)
{
    String[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path, found, SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    foreach (String file in files)
        files.Add(file);
}
```