# Returning specific file type from sub directory

Tags: c#, windows

By implying this call I am getting the name of current directory.I have a list of sub-directories inside a directory.

```
Users\Xeon\Documents\Visual Studio2013\Projects\Consolesocket1\Consolesocket1\Data
```

After this call I get return value named folder which is sub folder inside it.This is one task I want to accomplish.
Now how can i retrieve files inside this selected each sub directory with specific file type

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   FolderBrowserDialog folderBrowserDlg = new FolderBrowserDialog();            
   folderBrowserDlg.ShowNewFolderButton = true;            
   DialogResult dlgResult = folderBrowserDlg.ShowDialog();
   if (dlgResult.Equals(DialogResult.OK))
   {               
     textBox1.Text = folderBrowserDlg.SelectedPath;                
     Environment.SpecialFolder rootFolder = folderBrowserDlg.RootFolder;
   }
}
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string[] extensions = { ".xml", ".ddg" };
   string[] dizi = Directory.GetFiles(textBox1.Text, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                    .Where(f => extensions.Contains(new FileInfo(f).Extension.ToLower())).ToArray();

   string[] dizin = Directory.GetDirectories(textBox1.Text, "P*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
   foreach (var i in dizin)
   {
     FileInfo f = new FileInfo(i);
     listBox1.Items.Add(f.Name);
   }
   string[] di = Directory.GetDirectories(textBox1.Text, "S*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
   foreach (var z in di)
   {
      FileInfo f = new FileInfo(z);
      listBox1.Items.Add(f.Name);
   }
}
```

Comment: Is it what you want?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14330295/how-can-directory-getfiles-multi-searchpattern-filters-c-sharp

Comment: yes I want such way but how to call for each sub directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did correctly by specifying the extensions, and using the
`SearchOption.AllDirections`.

The first `dizin` variable will contain all files.

Comment: how to call for each sub directory