# Why the method is not returning files from the main directory and how can i specify many extentions?

Tags: c#, winforms

This is the code in my method :

```
t = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
string[] textfiles = ApplyAllFiles(t, "*.txt", ProcessFile).ToArray();
```

Then i did also:

```
s = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
string[] textfiles = ApplyAllFiles(s, "*.jpg", ProcessFile).ToArray();
```

And the ApplyAllFiles method:

```
static void ProcessFile(string path) {/* ... */}

static IEnumerable<string> ApplyAllFiles(string folder, string searchPattern, Action<string> fileAction)
{
     IEnumerable<string> files = Directory.GetFiles(folder, searchPattern);
     foreach (string file in files)
     {
         fileAction(file);
     }

     foreach (string subDir in Directory.GetDirectories(folder))
     {
         try
         {
             files = files.Concat(ApplyAllFiles(subDir, searchPattern, fileAction));
         }
         catch
         {
              // swallow, log, whatever
         }
      }

      return files;
}
```

1. Its not getting files from the main directory for example the first main directory is:
   C:\Users\bout0_000\Documents
   And i have in this directory some text files. It will get all the text files from sub
   directories in Documents but it will never get the text file that are in              C:\Users\bout0_000\Documents
2. How can i get more then one extention for example i did "*.jpg" but i want also to get bmp files png files and gif files.

Comment: For some info on multiple extensions and `Directory.GetFiles()` look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/163162/can-you-call-directory-getfiles-with-multiple-filters

Comment: I ran your code unchanged on my system and it successfully returns TXT files from the 'main' folder, meaning my `Documents` folder.

Comment: David the textfiles is working but this s = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonPictures); give me : C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures but i want it to give me like the textfiles the variable t: C:\\Users\\bout0_000\\Documents so Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonPictures); i want it to give me: C:\\Users\\bout0_000\\Pictures how can i do it ?

Comment: `Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures` would give you the correct filepath for a given user as opposed to the Public Shared folder.

Comment: Not sure that I understand what you just asked in the comment, but I think I might.  Instead of `Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonPictures` please try `Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures`  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just use [`SearchOption.AllDirectories`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143448.aspx)?  Then you won't need the `Concat` or the recursion.  You could just say

```
static void ApplyAllFiles(string folder, string searchPattern, Action<string> fileAction)
{
    foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(folder, searchPattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        fileAction(file);
}
```

Here is the [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316.aspx) in question.  Or you can use [`EnumerateFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles.aspx).

Unfortunately, the `searchPattern` argument doesn't support multiple extension patterns, so you'll have to do that yourself.  Something like this:

```
static void ApplyAllFiles(string folder, Action<string> fileAction)
{
    foreach (string file in
             Directory
             .EnumerateFiles(folder, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
             .Where(f => new[] {".jpg", ".txt"}.Contains(Path.GetExtension(f))))
        fileAction(file);
}
```

Comment: harpo the reason i dont want to use  SearchOption.AllDirectories is that for example on my wife laptop im getting exception access denied on some sub directories from Documents and i saw that the solution is not to use  SearchOption.AllDirectories but recursion . So i dont want to use SearchOption.AllDirectories at all.

Comment: If you're getting access denied, then it's not going to matter which method you use.  If you need to selectively omit certain directories, you can use a method similar to the second sample, where you individually test file extensions.  (Alternatively, you could just have your wife grant your account access :)