# Turn comma-separated string into GetFiles SearchPattern

Tags: c#, string, join, split, getfiles

I have the following code:

```
private string[] FindExistingDocuments()
{
    string supportedImageFormats = "jpg,pdf,doc,docx,xlsx";

    DirectoryInfo documentPath = new DirectoryInfo("...");

    string supportedFileTypes = String.Join(",*.", supportedImageFormats.Split(','));
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(documentPath.FullName, supportedFileTypes, SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    return files;
}
```

Which functions as a way of searching for a specific list of file types but the problem with the current code is that `String.Join` does not put the separator at the first item (which makes sense).

So my `supportedFileTypes` turns out to be:

```
jpg,*.pdf,*.doc,*.docx,*.xlsx
```

But I want it to be:

```
*.jpg,*.pdf,*.doc,*.docx,*.xlsx
```

Can I somehow make this in a pretty clean way?

Note: I cannot alter the contents of `supportedImageFormats`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
string newStr = string.Join(",", supportedImageFormats.Split(',')
                                     .Select(r => "*." + r));
```

Output: `Console.WriteLine(newStr);`

```
*.jpg,*.pdf,*.doc,*.docx,*.xlsx
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I just realised GetFiles does not support multiple extensions so I had to use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/163162/can-you-call-directory-getfiles-with-multiple-filters :(

Answer (score 1):

I recognize the elegance of the answer from @Habib, but there is also a non LINQ answer

```
 string newStr = "*." + string.Join(",*.", supportedImageFormats.Split(','));
```

By the way, all of this is pointless because you can't pass that kind of pattern to Directory.GetFiles