# How do I delete all files of a particular type from a folder

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm using the following code for deleting all the files in a particular folder:

```
Sub DeleteFilesFromFolder(Folder As String)
    If Directory.Exists(Folder) Then
        For Each _file As String In Directory.GetFiles(Folder)
            File.Delete(_file)
        Next
        For Each _folder As String In Directory.GetDirectories(Folder)

            DeleteFilesFromFolder(_folder)
        Next

    End If

End Sub
```

Calling function:

```
DeleteFilesFromFolder("C:\New Folder")
```

Now, I want to delete all the `*.pdf` documents from new folder. How can I delete only the `*.pdf`files from the folder (including the sub-folders)?

Comment: Directory.GetFile should return the filename including the extension. If so it would be as simple as 

`IF _file.contains(".pdf") Then
file.Delete(_file)
END IF`

Alternatively, add a filter to the GetFile
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/163162/can-you-call-directory-getfiles-with-multiple-filters

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`Directory.GetFiles()` allows you to apply a search pattern and return you the files that match this pattern.

```
Sub DeleteFilesFromFolder(Folder As String)
    If Directory.Exists(Folder) Then
        For Each _file As String In Directory.GetFiles(Folder, "*.pdf")
            File.Delete(_file)
        Next
        For Each _folder As String In Directory.GetDirectories(Folder)
            DeleteFilesFromFolder(_folder)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Check the MSDN link for more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You just have to check the extension before proceeding to deletion;

```
Sub DeleteFilesFromFolder(Folder As String)
If Directory.Exists(Folder) Then
    For Each _file As String In Directory.GetFiles(Folder)
       If System.IO.Path.GetExtension(_file) = ".pdf" Then  ' Check extension
          File.Delete(_file)
       End If
    Next
    For Each _folder As String In Directory.GetDirectories(Folder)
        DeleteFilesFromFolder(_folder)
    Next
End If
End Sub
```