# How to display two values for one string variable C# Winform?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to be able to display two file extensions in the listbox but apparently the code only works if i place one value (ex: string extension = "*.png";) on my code.

```
        string path = cmbDrive.Text;
        string extension = "*.txt" + "*.png";
        foreach (string s in FileUts.GetFiles(path, extension))
        {
            lbDBview.Items.Add(s);
        }
        if (lbDBview.Items.Count == 0) 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No Files found!");
        }
```

Comment: Here is a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/163162/can-you-call-directory-getfiles-with-multiple-filters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear what `FileUts.GetFiles()` is doing exactly.

If it is calling [OpenFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx) try

```
extension = "TXT|*.txt;PNG|*.png"
```

If it is calling [Directory.GetFiles()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getfiles(v=vs.110).aspx), you cannot specify multiple criteria to *searchPattern*.  However, you could combine two results, e.g.

```
foreach (string s in FileUts.GetFiles(path, extension1)
                     .Union(FileUts.GetFiles(path, extension2)))
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

Note also the comment, that you can make a single call to [Directory.GetFiles() and use Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163162/can-you-call-directory-getfiles-with-multiple-filters), assuming nothing else interesting happens in `FileUts.GetFiles()`.

Comment: Thank you so much Mr. Eric J. your code really help me. :)