# How to find list of file path in files and in sub folders of C Drive based on different extension through WMI in C#

Tags: c#, wmi, wmi-query

I need to search files of the extension mp3 and many more from the whole C Drive and store only its path in specific list string,currently I'm just printing on the Console  I get repetitive results too .I just want to skip even if one file is found.How is it possible to search all type of extension file apart with mp3 and avi and many more

```
List<string> filesmediaFound = new List<string>();
                            string machinename = Environment.MachineName;
                            string wmifilepath = @"\\" + machinename + @"\root\CIMV2";
                            string fileSearchQuery = @"SELECT * FROM CIM_DataFile WHERE Drive='C:' AND Extension = 'mp3'";

                            // ObjectQuery querystring = new ObjectQuery(fileSearchQuery);
                            using (ManagementObjectSearcher search = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wmifilepath, fileSearchQuery)) 
                            {
                                foreach (ManagementObject result in search.Get())
                                {

                                    Console.WriteLine( result["Path"].ToString());
                                }
                            }
```

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to search for files then you can use Directory class in System.IO

```
Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\", "*.mp3". SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

Comment: Well it doesnt allow me to search files that have access denied like Users Folder.. I want to search them through WMI @Sandeep

Comment: I doubt if you will be able to access those folders with WMI. You can handle such scenario in your code. Any particular reason to use WMI api

Comment: Was facing difficulty with IO  check out the link[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31581772/how-to-get-file-path-from-c-program-files-folder-in-c-sharp-while-searching-spe] so swtiched to find out with WMI @Sandeep

Comment: I found a possible solution to your problem in the comments: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/163162/can-you-call-directory-getfiles-with-multiple-filters. In case that doesn't work you may want to run the recurse through the directory yourself.