# how to select files from a list from a particular directory

Tags: c#, list, directory, getfiles

I know I can use

```
 Directory.GetFiles(sourceDirectory, pattern);
```

To get ALL the files with a particular pattern.  However, I'm curious as to how would one get only the files wanted (i.e. from a list of some sort) with that same pattern?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you call Directory.GetFiles() with multiple filters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/163162/can-you-call-directory-getfiles-with-multiple-filters)

Comment: i'm not really looking for filters, per say.  I'd be looking for something like the following:

    Directory.GetFiles(sourceDirectory, pattern, listOfFilesToFind);

Answer (score 0):

Dont think you can do straight out of GetFiles, you can surely filter them though....

```
private static string[] GetFiles(string sourceFolder, string filters, System.IO.SearchOption searchOption, List<string> fileNames )
        {
            return System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sourceFolder, filters, searchOption).Where(fileNames.Contains).ToArray();
        }
```

Comment: I finally found a way to do it w/ GetFiles, but only w/ a Lambda expression using SelectMany

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] filePaths = filesToReturn.SelectMany(f => Directory.GetFiles(sourceDirectory, f)).ToArray();
```