# Copy all pdf files from one path to another without loop in c#

Tags: c#, file, pdf, directory, copy

I am trying to copy all PDF files (.pdf) from the source folder to the destination. I have written it using a `foreach` loop, but I want to do it without for or any loop. Is there a way to do that, and if so, how?

My Code

```
string sourcePath = @"D:\DataArchiveTest\From";
string targetPath = @"D:\DataArchiveTest\To";
foreach (var sourceFilePath in Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath))
{
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(sourceFilePath);
    string destinationFilePath = Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);
    if (fileName.ToUpper().Contains(".PDF"))
    {
        System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFilePath, destinationFilePath, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to copy the entire contents of a directory in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58744/best-way-to-copy-the-entire-contents-of-a-directory-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Actually the sourceFolder may contain thousands of files. If we use  for loop then it affect the performance in my application

Answer (score 2):

you can do something like this:

```
string sourcePath = @"D:\DataArchiveTest\From";
string targetPath = @"D:\DataArchiveTest\To";

var dir = new DirectoryInfo(sourcePath);
FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles("*.pdf");

foreach (var item in files)
{
   File.Copy(item.FullName, Path.Combine(targetPath, item.Name), true); // overwrite = true 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try filter before copy:

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\path", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                .Where(s => s.EndsWith(".pdf") );
```

refer : [Can you call Directory.GetFiles() with multiple filters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163162/can-you-call-directory-getfiles-with-multiple-filters)

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned in the comments, source directory has lot of files and you want to limit this to `Pdf` files alone (to gain performance), you could use an  overloaded [`Directory.GetFiles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316(v=vs.110).aspx) allow you to specify **search pattern**.

```
Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath, "*.pdf");
```

Now we can you simplify your code to

```
string sourcePath = @"D:\DataArchiveTest\From";
string targetPath = @"D:\DataArchiveTest\To";
foreach (var sourceFilePath in Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath, "*.pdf"))
{
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(sourceFilePath);
        string destinationFilePath = Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);
        System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFilePath, destinationFilePath, true);
}
```

Comment: But I don't want to use a foreach loop. May be we can use Parallel Each loop ??

Comment: We could do that, in fact that's great idea.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
string target = @"D:\DataArchiveTest\To\";
string source = @"D:\DataArchiveTest\From\";

string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(source, ".*pdf", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

foreach (string item in files)
{
    //Add try - catch
    File.Copy(item, target + item.Replace(source, ""),true);
}
```

Make sure you include a '\' at the end of your source path