# Use Razor to display all images in specific folder

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

How to display list of images from specific folder that contains unique folder name based on the Id passed from model?

For instance, I have two different folders namely "RestaurantA" and "RestaurantB" respectively.

If RestaurantA is clicked, I want to show all the images in folder "RestaurantA", regardless of the image name.

```
<img src="~/menu/@(Model.Id)/1.jpg" class="materialboxed menu-photo" />
```

**Edit**

I forgot to mention that in each folder, the names of the image will be in sequential form. Like in "RestaurantA" folder has 1.jpg, 2.jpg etc. I saw someone posted will have to use for loop in Javascript. Is there any other way other than using Javascript? Perhaps using Razor syntax.

Comment: from controller send list of images within that folder and from view, iterate over to produce multiple img tag

Comment: `var files = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(%path to your folder%)).GetFiles();`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/163162/can-you-call-directory-getfiles-with-multiple-filters

Answer (score 2):

You can do this inside razor code at your cshtml file:

```
@
{
//First get the directory on which your all your images reside
string strDirectory = Server.MapPath(Url.Content("~/*YourPathHere*/"));

//Get all files on the directory and store it on string array
string[] strFiles = Directory.GetFiles(strDirectory);

string strFileName = string.Empty;

//Loop on each file and attach it on img tag
    foreach (var strFile in strFiles)
      {
         strFileName = Path.GetFileName(strFile);
         <img id="myImg" src="@Url.Content("~/*YourPathHere*/" + strFileName)"/>
      }   
}
```

Comment: is it possible to use model data in the image tag ? like this `<img src="@Url.Content("~/menu/@(Model.Id)/" + strFileName)" class="materialboxed menu-photo" />` bcos I've tried and got error