# Display only certain file types from a directory in a listview

Tags: c#, listview, pdf, treeview

I want my listview to only display .PDF files

here is my current code to populate the listview

but I have no idea how to filter the filetypes to only a certain file extension

```
    void treeView1_NodeMouseClick(object sender,
TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
    {
        uplevel = "";
        TreeNode newSelected = e.Node;
        //sub =


        listView1.Items.Clear();
        DirectoryInfo nodeDirInfo = (DirectoryInfo)newSelected.Tag;
        ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem[] subItems;
        ListViewItem item = null;



        foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in nodeDirInfo.GetDirectories())
        {
            item = new ListViewItem(dir.Name, 0);
            subItems = new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem[]
                      {new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(item, "Directory"),
               new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(item,
            dir.LastAccessTime.ToShortDateString())};
            item.SubItems.AddRange(subItems);
            listView1.Items.Add(item);
        }
        foreach (FileInfo file in nodeDirInfo.GetFiles())
        {
            item = new ListViewItem(file.Name, 1);
            subItems = new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem[]
                      { new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(item, "File"),
               new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(item,
            file.LastAccessTime.ToShortDateString())};

            item.SubItems.AddRange(subItems);
            listView1.Items.Add(item);
        }

        listView1.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

of course you can specify the file type in `GetFiles` as like this:

```
string searchPattern = "*.pdf";
// This pattern will filter files having any name and extension as .pdf
foreach (FileInfo file in nodeDirInfo.GetFiles(searchPattern)
{

    // add items as per your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See [Can you call Directory.GetFiles() with multiple filters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163162/can-you-call-directory-getfiles-with-multiple-filters)

Get the files filtered before you attempt to list them?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the GetFiles() override that allows for a searchPattern to be send in. See the document below on how to use the overloaded parameter.

[DirectoryInfo.GetFiles()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8he88b63(v=vs.110).aspx)