# Get Image file from folder in FileInfo

Tags: c#, asp.net, console-application

I am making a console application and from a particular folder I want to get only the images with specific extension.

Below code I am trying but it's retrieving all the files from the particular path.

```
string[] extensions = { ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png", ".gif", ".tif" };
FileInfo[] files = new DirectoryInfo(SourcePath).GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

How can I set extension on `FileInfo[]`?

**Updated Issue**

[image]

Answer

```
List<String> ImageFiles = Directory.GetFiles(SourcePath, "*.*",
             SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            .Where(file => new string[] { ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png", ".gif", ".tif" }
            .Contains(Path.GetExtension(file)))
            .ToList();
            List<FileInfo> files = new List<FileInfo>();
            foreach (string filess in ImageFiles)
            {
                string replace = filess.Replace(@"\", "/");
                files.Add(new FileInfo(replace.Split('/').Last()));
            }
```

here how Can I get rid from for each loop as I am only needing file name and not the whole path

Comment: Right now there is absolutely no connection between your `extensions` and the call to `GetFiles`. You'll have to either filter the list of files or iterate the extensions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you call Directory.GetFiles() with multiple filters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163162/can-you-call-directory-getfiles-with-multiple-filters)

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer 
 
Is it not possible to get data in FileInfo[] files?

Comment: How said that's not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following code snippet . Updated the answer as per your question

```
void Main()
{


List<string> ext = new List<string> { ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png", ".gif", ".tif" }; 
FileInfo[] files = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\temp").EnumerateFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories) 
.Where(path => ext.Contains(Path.GetExtension(path.Name))) 
.Select(x => new FileInfo(x.FullName)).ToArray();
}

// Define other methods and classes here
```

Comment: A `ToLower` would also include files like `test.JPG`. Also the `GetExtensions` method includes the `.` so it would have to be present in `ext` too.

Comment: Is it not possible to get data in FileInfo[] files?

Comment: Yes it's possible FileInfo[] smFiles = di.GetFiles("*.jpg");
    foreach (FileInfo fi in smFiles)
    {
       
    }

Comment: GetFiles returns FileInfo. what is your requirement

Comment: @santoshsingh what for all image files like jpg, bmp, png in fileinfo

Comment: I was receiving issue from your code see updated question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162157/discussion-between-santosh-singh-and-mitesh-jain).

Answer (score 3):

Please use the below code.

```
 List<String> ImageFiles = Directory.GetFiles(DirPath, "*.*",
                 SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                .Where(file => new string[] { ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png", ".gif", ".tif" }
                .Contains(Path.GetExtension(file)))
                .ToList();
                List<FileInfo> images = new List<FileInfo>();
                foreach (string fileName in ImageFiles)
                {
                images.Add(new FileInfo(fileName));
                }
```

Comment: Is it not possible to get data in FileInfo[] files?

Comment: Can it be done with out foreach loop and can I only get the file names instead of getting full path?

Comment: "Regex.Match(fileName, @"[^\\]*$").Value"                                                               Using the  regular expression you will get the filename without path.

Answer (score 2):

I think it will be better to use Directory.EnumerateFiles instead of GetFiles. EnumerateFiles method is not waiting until all files are loaded. Which can be more efficient with large number of files.

```
void Main()
{
    string[] ext = new List<string> {".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png", ".gif", ".tif"};
    FileInfo[] files = new DirectoryInfo(SourcePath).EnumerateFiles(@"C:\temp", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
     .Where(path => ext.Contains(Path.GetExtension(path.ToLower()));
}
```

UPDATE:

Answer to updated question.

```
    var ImageFilenames = Directory.EnumerateFiles(SourcePath, "*.*",
     SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Where(file => new string[] { ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png", ".gif", ".tif" }
    .Contains(Path.GetExtension(file)))
    .Select(p => p.Substring(p.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1));
```

Comment: What is it? What issue?