# Regex Directory.GetFiles Illegal characters in path c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Below code triggers exception:

```
string[] filenames=Directory.GetFiles( "path from config",
"*MAIN.txt|*CONT.txt", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).ToArray()
```

I want to pull all files into a array from a directory containing `MAIN.txt` or `CONT.txt` in the file name.
 But when i run the code it is giving me `System.ArgumentException, Illegal characters in path exception`.

Comment: Welcome to SO! The second parameter is not a regular expression. It is a "search string" that can only accept * and ? characters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you call Directory.GetFiles() with multiple filters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163162/can-you-call-directory-getfiles-with-multiple-filters)

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate further, the reason you are getting the `ArgumentException` is because the second parameter is not valid.

The overload of the `Directory.GetFiles` method that you are using is expecting a `string path`, `string searchPattern`, and a `SearchOption searchOption`.

The `searchPattern` is not a regular expression. You can only use a combination of * and ? characters.

**From the documentation:**

> The search string to match against the names of files in path. This
>   parameter can contain a combination of valid literal path and wildcard
>   (* and ?) characters, but it doesn't support regular expressions.

Alternative implementation using the `System.Linq` `Concat` extension method:

```
string[] mainFileNames = Directory.GetFiles(@"/Some/Path", "*MAIN.txt", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
string[] contFileNames = Directory.GetFiles(@"/Some/Path", "*CONT.txt", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

string[] allFileNames = mainFileNames.Concat(contFileNames).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Those aren't regular expressions. Anyway, `Directory.GetFiles` doesn't support filename expressions with the `|` character. You'll need to call that method twice, and then combine the arrays together.

```
string[] mainNames=Directory.GetFiles("path from config","*MAIN.txt",SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
string[] contNames=Directory.GetFiles("path from config","*CONT.txt",SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

string[] fileNames= new string[mainNames.Length + contNames.Length];
Array.Copy(mainNames, fileNames, mainNames.Length);
Array.Copy(contNames, 0, fileNames, mainNames.Length, contNames.Length);
```