# How to access directories with Pattern ( NUMBER.NAME ) by number only

Tags: c#, .net, regex, path, directory

I have directories for example with this pattern:

- 0001.MyFolder
- 0002.MyFolder2
- 0003.MyFolder3

Inputs is only number of directory ( example enter 0002 -> then get items in MyFolder 3)

and how to return path of directory by its number ?
example : enter 0002 return C:\MyPath\0002.MyFolder2

The pattern is

Number (dot) String

So i need access any directory by the number before dot.

Comment: What have you tried, because this is not particularly hard, and there is no need for regex

Comment: [`Directory.GetFiles`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=netframework-4.8) would be a relevant place to start. While a Regex can be used, it's not required. Also see [`Path.GetFileName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilename?view=netframework-4.8) and `String.StartsWith`, etc (remember that files are case-insensitive on Windows, although such is not relevant for numbers). I would probably use Single from LINQ for the filter as it'll trivially abort on 'oops' cases.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you call Directory.GetFiles() with multiple filters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163162/can-you-call-directory-getfiles-with-multiple-filters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best approach for figuring out something, is to start googling and reading the documentation

[GetDirectories(String, String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getdirectories?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_Directory_GetDirectories_System_String_System_String_)

> Returns the names of subdirectories (including their paths) that match
>   the specified search pattern in the specified directory.
>
> ---
>
> `searchPattern` can be a combination of literal and wildcard
>   characters, but it doesn't support regular expressions. The following
>   wildcard specifiers are permitted in `searchPattern`.
>
> **Wildcard specifier  Matches**
>
> - `*` (asterisk)  Zero or more characters in that position.
> - `?` (question mark) Zero or one character in that position.

So here is a little method that can help you

```
  public string GetFolder(string index, string path)
     => Directory.GetDirectories(path, $"{index}.*")
                 .FirstOrDefault();
```

**Usage**

```
var dir = GetFolder("0001", @"C:\MyHomeWorkFolder");

if(dir != null)
   // we have found something
```