# Is there an or keyword for GetDirectories searchPattern parameter?

Tags: vb.net

I am using `Directory.GetDirectories()` to get a list of folders that meet a certain criteria by using its `searchPattern` parameter.

I am only looking for any folders containing a specific word, say `alphabet`, my code is as follows:

`Directory.GetDirectories(rootToSearch, "*alphabet*")`

But, there is a common abbreviation that I know to expect for this word, say `abc`. If I was searching in Windows File Explorer I could search for `*alphabet* OR *abc*` and it would work as expected, however putting this as the `searchPattern` results in the function finding no folders, presumably because it is taking it as one search term including `OR` as a literal, instead of 2 terms delineated with `OR`.

Is there any way to achieve an `OR` statement in the search pattern? The [MSDN says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getdirectories?view=net-5.0):

> The search string to match against the names of subdirectories in path. This parameter can contain a combination of valid literal and wildcard characters, but it doesn't support regular expressions.

So I know that I can't use Regular Expressions. I tried using `|`, but that results in an `Illegal characters in path` error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you call Directory.GetFiles() with multiple filters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163162/can-you-call-directory-getfiles-with-multiple-filters)

Comment: @41686d6564 Partially. I've answered my question to encompass how to mimic `GetDirectories()` more fully. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163162/can-you-call-directory-getfiles-with-multiple-filters) you can use LINQ to filter an array of all directories on the root, instead of using the `searchPattern`

But that question used `GetFiles()` and there are certain things to take into account when using the solution for `GetDirectories()`

To ensure that your search pattern is indeed being used only against the folder name rather than the entire path, use `DirectoryInfo`

`LCase()` is also used to mimic `GetDirectories()` accordingly.

```
Dim folders = Directory.GetDirectories(rootToSearch) _
    .Where(Function(s)
               Return LCase(New DirectoryInfo(s).Name).Contains("abc") Or LCase(New DirectoryInfo(s).Name).Contains("alphabet")
           End Function)
```